# Why my bot doesn't understand when I enter a command (and answer with the default mode) only in channels and not in private message?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I’m creating an echo bot for telegram. The bot works perfectly in private message but when I put it on a channel I have some issues. When a enter one of the specific commands, it answer with the default function and i don’t understand why it acts like this. Thanks for any help.

```
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, Application, ContextTypes, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters
# manage coroutine
import asyncio

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    
# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments update and context.

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    user = update.effective_user
    message = update.effective_message
    # collect the chat id of the messagge
    chat_id = message.chat_id
    response = rf"""Hello {user.mention_html()}! Let's start """

    # send the message to the chat 
    await asyncio.create_task(context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=response))

async def toHelp(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    message = update.effective_message
    # collect the chat id of the messagge
    chat_id = message.chat_id
    response = """ Help """

    # send the message to the chat 
    await asyncio.create_task(context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=response))

async def predict(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    message = update.effective_message
    # collect the chat id of the messagge
    chat_id = message.chat_id
    response = "prediction"
    print(update.effective_message.text)
    # send the message to the chat 
    await asyncio.create_task(context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=response))

async def echo(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    message = update.effective_message
    # collect the chat id of the messagge
    chat_id = message.chat_id
    response = "Echo !"
    print(update.effective_message.text)
    # send the message to the chat 
    await asyncio.create_task(context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=response))

def main()->None:

    TOKEN = '-------'
    
    # Create the Application and pass it your bot's token.
    application = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    # wait for different commands
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start),group = 1)
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("predict", predict),group = 2)
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", toHelp), group = 3)

    message_handler = MessageHandler(filters.COMMAND, echo)
    
    # depends on the question the script will trigger a command or the default echo message
    application.add_handler(message_handler)

    application.run_polling()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I just want to make the bot correctly answers to the commands in any situation. But when I use it on a channel and not in private message, it answers with the default command.

Answer (score 0):

IISC, you only register the `message_handler` via `Application.add_handler`.You have to register all the remaining handlers in order to make your bot listen to them. Also this page could be helpful for you: [What messages can my Bot see?](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-messages-can-my-bot-see)